# How to convert bathymetry sounding data to DEM (digital elevation model)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem

https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/docucomp/page?url=http://surveys.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/NOS/hsmdb/H04001-H06000/H05455_hsmdb.xml&view=hydro/survey&header=none

I downloaded the bathymetry sounding data in xyz format but noticed that the depth is positive. Why is there positive depth when the gps location is clearly on water?

With ArcGis 10.4 I was able to extract xyz data from the DEM file and plot the image below. The DEM file was used since it covered most of the area needed except for H as shown below, that's why I was trying to use bathymetry sounding data. Orange dots= depth 0, green dots is <0.

[image: orange dot=depth 0, green is <0, and bathymetry for H is needed.]

If I use bathymetry sounding data there is many orange dots with depth 0.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. In your question title you ask how to create a DEM but in the question itself you talk about extracting data from the DEM file. Also can you add what software and version you are using as well as data file format.

Comment: I don't understand what "for free" in your title has to do with your question either.

Comment: [wet] Sandbanks and Wave Oscillation give positive bathy heights https://www.researchgate.net/figure/284435043_fig1_Fig-1-A-map-showing-the-bathymetry-of-Swansea-Bay-with-the-Mumbles-tide-gauge

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the vertical datum they are using and its relationship to depth. For example, in coastal Washington the mean high tide line is about 2.2 meters NAVD 88 and the tide range is 5 m, that means if they took soundings during high tide the elevation would be positive an the "mean sea level" elevation of zero would be several hundred yards offshore.

In this case they would have been using local mean sea level based on local tide guages (e.g., see https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/stations.html?type=Water+Levels). You should check out the relationship between MSL at your local and NGVD29 (Sea Level Datum 1929).